# How can "SELECT 1 + 1" :: IO [Only Int] be of type Query in this simple postgresql example?

Tags: postgresql, haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to understand this simple postgresql example in haskell

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect localPG
  mapM_ print =<< (query_ conn "SELECT 1 + 1" :: IO [Only Int])
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#v:query_

```
 query_ :: FromRow r => Connection -> Query -> IO [r]
```

How can `"SELECT 1 + 1" :: IO [Only Int]` be a `Query?`

Looking at the source for the type `Query` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.4.10.0/docs/src/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-Types.html#Query doesn't help me:

```
newtype Query = Query {
      fromQuery :: ByteString
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable)
```

I don't see a connection between `IO [Only Int]` and `Query`

Comment: `f x :: a` is parsed as `(f x) :: a`, not as `f (x :: a)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type annotation `IO [Only Int]` applies to the whole expression `query_ conn "SELECT 1 + 1"`, not just to its last argument.

The string `"SELECT 1 + 1"` by itself can be of type `Query` because the type `Query` has an instance of `IsString`.

This is how string literals work in Haskell (provided `OverloadedStrings` is on): a string literal has type `IsString a => a`, and the compiler uses the `fromString` method to convert the actual string to the expected type.

Comment: why do I need to make the entire thing `IO [Only Int]` though?

Comment: Because there is no other source for the compiler to determine the type